# Javascript Function Variable Passing Syntax Issue

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to pass variables into a Javascript function and running into a problem that I don't understand.

This is fine.

```
<select name="AppointmentTimeDropDownList" id="username" onchange="checkUserName(this.value, document.forms['CustomerInteractionForm'].elements['AppointmentDateTextBox'].value)">
```

But this give me a syntax error my IDE says its missing ; before statement.

```
<select name="AppointmentTimeDropDownList" id="username" onchange="checkUserName(this.value, document.forms['CustomerInteractionForm'].elements['AppointmentDateTextBox'].value), document.forms['CustomerInteractionForm'].elements['AppointmentAssignedToDropDownList'].value)">
```

Comment: You have an additional `)` at `.elements['AppointDateTextBox'].value),` that is likely there from your original statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you have an errant `)` here:

```
... .elements['AppointmentDateTextBox'].value), d ...
```

Comment: Derp, sometimes someone else just needs to look at your code, thanks!

Comment: Not to start an editor war, but if you're not already, using a text editor that highlights matching brackets, braces, and parenthesis, these sort of mistakes can become more obvious.